# VirtualDocumentRoot issue

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Good Day.

I'm setting up a mac for local development and have configured dnsmasq.conf with the following:

```
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

My wish is to run sites locally by `http://client1.ext.dev/index.html` which will map to a local folder of `/www/sites/client1.ext/htdocs/index.html`. Of course the variables here are `client#` and it's associated `ext` which could be any normal TLD -- .com, .net, .info, etc.

I've tried every permutation that I could think of, but I can't seem to get the httpd.conf to map correctly (technically my httpd-vhosts.conf file).

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /www/sites/%-2+/htdocs
  #ServerName sites.dev 
  ServerAlias *.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

Using this uri in my browser `client1.com.dev/index.html`, my log files reads `File does not exist: /www/sites/client1.com`
Why won't the remaining mapping of VirtualDocumentRoot not work? (The "/htdocs" part is not being added.).

Many posts indicate that it should, but the man page (http://goo.gl/Ghff5G) doesn't show any additional directories beyond the %-mapping.

I've also tried RewriteRules within my  directives to no avail (and I'm pretty sure I wasn't doing that correctly).

**Bonus**

If I have a sub-domain, my browser just goes out to OpenDNS (which I have configured to default after my internal IP) and says it can't find `sub.client1.com.dev` which I'd like to map to `/www/sites/sub.client1.com/htdocs`.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a silly question, but does `/www/sites/client1.com` exist?

Comment: yes, as does /www/sites/client1.com/htdocs/index.html

Comment: Ok, sorta solved.

Comment: Ok, sorta solved. `http://client1.com.dev`  still not resolving, so I cp the dir and renamed to `http://anything.com.dev` -- and it works. Grrr. Still beating head as `http://client1.com.dev` is not. However, `http://client1.com.dev/index.html` DOES work (as does `http://anyting.com.dev/index.html` Ugh. No clue as to why. I don't see any differences anywhere.

Comment: Still trying to figure out the sub-domain, so `http://sub.client1.com.dev` maps to `/www/sites/sub.client1.com/htdocs`. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

As you've got a 1:1 mapping you should just be able to use the full URL with;

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /www/sites/%0/htdocs
  ServerName %0
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

The above should also work for subdomains.

I do something similar apart from I just use a .dev TLD in place of the actual live one and also alias to xip.io for devices that don't use my local dnsmasq dns.

```
# Any .dev folder in ~/Sites
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/phunky/Sites/%1.0.%-1.0/public"
    ServerName %-2.0.%-1.0
    ServerAlias %-2.0.%-1.0.*.xip.io
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I could figure out how to get subdomains to map to alternative folders within the VirtualDocumentRoot i'd be a very happy man.